# iOS Facebook token Permissions birthday

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, permissions, token

Hello guys I need some help   I need Facebook token  with necessary permits to show birthday user...! It is a necessary requirement for my registration API  I'm looking at Facebook developer I'm using all the methods but I still have birthday data

```
 #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
 #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>






- (IBAction)loginFaceboook:(id)sender {

FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)

 {
     if (error)
     {
         // Process error
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled)
     {
         // Handle cancellations
     }
     else
     {

         if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
             // TODO: publish content.
         } else {

             FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
             [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                    fromViewController:self
                                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                                   //TODO: process error or result.
                                               }];
         }

         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
         {
           NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
             [self fetchUserInfo];
         }
     }
 }];
}
-(void)fetchUserInfo
{

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{

       // NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken     currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name, email, birthday"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             _auth_token = [[FBSDKAccessToken     currentAccessToken]tokenString];
             NSLog(@"Token Facebook is : %@",_auth_token);

  ///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\\///\\\//   /\\\///\\\///\\\\///\\\///\\\///\\\

             AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
             //[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
             manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
             manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
             NSDictionary *params = @{@"access_token":_auth_token};
             [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
             [manager POST:@"http:myUrl/api/facebook/" parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
                 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
                 if (responseObject)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"POST data JSON returned: %@", responseObject);

                     NSLog(@"DATA SEND OK");

                 }
             } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"ERROR NO SEND DATA FROM FACEBOOK.. %@", error);
             }];

             _LoginFacebook.alpha=0;
Menu *VC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[VC2 setModalTransitionStyle:(UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve)];
[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:nil ];

             NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
             [prefs setObject:self.auth_token forKey:@"tokenF"];
             [prefs synchronize];
             NSLog(@"Saved Toke %@",prefs);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
         }
     }];

}

}
```

info from console the data is correct but are exchanged for x not provide personal information

```
 email = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@aol.com";
 id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
 name = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
 Token Facebook is : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx......!
```

Answer (score 1):

While writing this code

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
```

Add **"public_profile"** along with that

```
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"]
```

Check if it works!

**EDIT**

As CBroe mentioned, we need **user_birthday** permission and I guess nowadays we have to take approval from facebook for this permission

[image]

Comment: Birthday is not part of public_profile, it needs `user_birthday` permission.

Comment: oh...yes, its not part of public_profile. I think for birthday we need to take approval from Facebook first nowadays

Comment: Yes I am trying this FBSDKLoginManager *login =     [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
       [login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
       }  but does not show me  birthday

Comment: already edited the answer. You will not get birthday. You first have to submit to facebook for review process

Comment: Yes Work I need user_birthday permission and I guess nowadays we have to take approval from facebook for this permission and [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_birthday"]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
- (IBAction)loginFaceboook:(id)sender {

FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_birthday"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if (error)
     {
         // Process error
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled)
     {
         // Handle cancellations
     }
     else
     {
         if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]   hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
             // TODO: publish content.
         } else {

             FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
             [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                    fromViewController:self
                                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                                   //TODO: process error or result.
                                               }];
         }

         if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
         {
             NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
             [self fetchUserInfo];
         }
     }
 }];
}
```